# NestedScrollView не полностью показывает информацию

Tags: android

Наткнулся на проблему что последние несколько TextView не отображаются или отображаются не полностью, в чем может быть проблема?Имею такую разметку:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|left"
        app:expandedTitleMargin="@dimen/title_margin"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/detail_backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/float_button_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_favorites"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/content_padding">

      ...Много TextView

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"` и `android:fillViewport="true"`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, помогло, но почему то не отображает layout_margin внизу

Comment: Похоже, это какая-то бага в `NestedScrollView`. Попробуйте добавить `android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"` или вообще переписать на `RecyclerView` - с ним такой проблемы быть не должно и костылями подпирать не придётся. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590672/nestedscrollview-cut-overlay-bottom-of-nested-fragments https://stackoverflow.com/a/30809092/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не помогло, при добавлении android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize", когда toolbar сжатый появляется белая полоска внизу экрана(размером с toolbar). Может с LinearLayout что то не так?

Comment: Других идей кроме переписывания под `RecyclerView` у меня нет)

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день. Запустил у себя этот код. Удаление android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical" и android:fillViewport="true" не помогло почему-то. Решилось следующим:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
           android:paddingBottom="88dp"
           android:clipToPadding="false">
```

Comment: Вы же понимаете что android:paddingBottom="88dp" по сути костыль. Я с этой целью и задал вопрос что бы такого избежать.

Comment: Поробуйте в Активити: Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar); setSupportActionBar(toolbar); android:layout_margin="16dp" - у NestedScrollView, а не у LinearLayout; android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical" и android:fillViewport="true" - удалить.